# jQuery POST not working - seems it should be

Tags: php, jquery

It's been a while since I've played with jQuery, so I'm wondering what I'm missing here.

I've set up a php page that writes a test txt file when the jQuery calls it.

The txt file is being written, so jQuery is finding the php page, but then displays my error alert, not my success one, so something is not working.

My php:

```
$testfile=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/test.txt';
$file5 = fopen ($testfile, "w");
fwrite($file5, 'testy');
fclose ($file5);
exit();
```

My jQuery:

```
var g = {
    r: 1
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test.php",
    cache: false,
    data: g,

    success: function (data) {
        alert('yay');
    },

    error: function (data) {
        alert('nay');
    }
});
```

Anything obvious I'm missing?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: check your browser console,

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is on the url you are requesting. Its hard to tell without know the type of error or without knowing your folder structure or if you are using any PHP framework. Please, write details

Try this--
`url: "test.php",`

Comment: Figured it out guys - I was returning to a Facebook connect login before the jQuery had a chance to pick up my php page exiting, so I moved return true to the success part of the function. Thanks for taking a look.